# Rolling Product Activation Scheme

Tags: activation, license-key

I've been pondering online product activation for a piece of software, but don't want to overburden the end user. Specifically, I'm concerned with handling the case when the user needs to reinstall the software in the event of hardware failure or upgrades.

I'm not attempting a Fort Knox of security, I don't plan on this application taking the world by storm.

Here are my thoughts, although my thinking may be off:

Assume the program must be connected to Internet to function and standard product activation techniques are applied.

- At program install, during license activation, the program could generate a key based on hardware configuration.
- This key would be transmitted to the server during activation.
- If the license is for one active install, and a second install is attempted - the server invalidates the first install. (This would be caught when the application is restarted on the first computer.)
- If a third install were attempted, it would invalidate the second install... and so on.

Ideally, there could only be as many active installs as their license was good for. But, newer installations would invalidate older ones.

Is there a method similar to this in use? 
 (I'm not exactly sure what to search for, but I've been reading general product activation questions.)

Additionally, is this a valid solution to the 'I upgraded my PC and had to reinstall the program' issue?